# How to get row from CellClick event?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-c#-express-2010

I need to get access to all the values in a DataGridViewRow, once the user clicks on a cell of that row. I would like to do that from the CellClick event for the DataGridView

Answer (score 1):

```
Datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].cells[0].value
```

this way you can check cell index and get value